# Looping through broken objects in Plone

Tags: python, plone, zope, zodb

I have a couple of broken objects that I wish to loop through in python script. My use case is as follows: I have renamed my custom product from `my.oldproduct` to `my.newproduct`. This has caused the previous objects saved with `my.oldproduct` to be broken and thus inaccessible. There is a workaround to this as detailed here: [Updating broken objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570902/renaming-my-packages-to-my-package)

Now what I want to do is create a python script in the ZMI to loop though all the broken content, change/update them, and thus cause them to be saved using my.newproduct.

I've been unable get the old objects as they are not listed. See a sample of my python script to list all the content in the site, yet they still do not show:

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

app = context.restrictedTraverse('/')
sm = app.plone.getSiteManager()

catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
results = catalog.searchResults()

count = 0
for obj in results:
    print obj.meta_type
    count += 1

print str("Found " + str(count) + " matching objects")

return printed
```

How can I get the broken objects from `my.oldproduct` to be listed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to traverse your whole ZODB manually, I'm afraid. If these objects are content objects, you should be able to use the standard OFS methods:

```
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime

import transaction
from zope.app.component.hooks import setSite
from Testing.makerequest import makerequest
from AccessControl.SecurityManagement import newSecurityManager

from my.newproduct.types import ArchetypesContentType


site_id = 'Plone'     # adjust to match your Plone site object id.
admin_user = 'admin'  # usually 'admin', probably won't need adjusting
app = makerequest(app)
site = app[site_id]
setSite(site)
user = app.acl_users.getUser(admin_user).__of__(site.acl_users)
newSecurityManager(None, user)


def treeWalker(root):
    # stack holds (parent, id, obj) tuples
    stack = deque([(None, None, root)])
    while stack:
        parent, id, next = stack.popleft()
        try:
            stack.extend((next, id, child) for id, child in next.objectItems())
        except AttributeError:
            # No objectItems method
            pass
        yield parent, id, next


count = 0
for parent, id, obj in treeWalker(site):
    if isinstance(obj, ArchetypesContentType):
        print 'Found content type object {} at {}'.format(id, '/'.join(object.getPhysicalPath()))
        obj._p_changed = True  # mark it as changed, force a commit
        count += 1
        if count % 100 == 0:
            # flush changes so far to disk to minimize memory usage
            transaction.savepoint(True)
            print '{} - Processed {} items'.format(datetime.now(), count)

transaction.commit()
```

This assumes you *already* included the work-around you linked to; there is little point in trying to do the above with `ZODB.broken.Broken` objects.

The above script acts as a `bin/instance run` script, run it as such:

```
bin/instance run path/to/this/script.py
```

You are going to process *everything* in the site, a fairly hefty process that will involve a lot of cache churn and possibly a large commit with potential conflicts. You do not want to run this as a through-the-web script, really.

Comment: Thanks Martijn but I'm unable to execute this code as a python script in the ZMI due to insufficient privileges. (RestrictedPython). I'm finding it odd to add this to my product's file system to allow executing the above considering it is a one-off task.

Comment: @Frankline: Fleshed it out some more; you *really* do not want to run this through-the-web. It is possible (replace the `deque` with a regular list and `.pop(0)` instead of `.popleft()`, leave out the `transaction.commit()` and `print` statements), I just don't think that'd be a good idea.